# Discord.js tenor gif rich embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Im currently trying to make a discord bot where when I type -gif *arguments* if displays a rich embed as shown in image with the according searched gif. For some reason, If I send the tenor api link by itself it works fine, but if I display it with an embed image, it displays nothing even using the same link. I've checked the link of the embed displayed image and it isn't a direct link ending in .gif, but if I add .gif to the end of that link, it is a direct link shown in my browser, but discord doesn't treat it like one.
**Code:**

```
const Tenor = require("tenorjs").client({
    "Key": "Ihaveakeyjustnotshowingit", // https://tenor.com/developer/keyregistration
    "Filter": "off", // "off", "low", "medium", "high", not case sensitive
    "Locale": "en_US", // Your locale here, case-sensitivity depends on input
    "MediaFilter": "minimal", // either minimal or basic, not case sensitive
    "DateFormat": "MM/D/YYYY - H:mm:ss A" // Change this accordingly
});

const fs = require('fs');
const discord = require('discord.js');


module.exports = {
    name: 'gif',
    aliases: ['tenor', 'gifsearch', 'gf'],
    category: 'Funny',
    utilisation: '{prefix}gif',

    execute(client, message, args) {

        const msgArgs = message.content.slice(this.name.length + 1)

        Tenor.Search.Query(msgArgs, "1").then(Results => {
            Results.forEach(Post => {
                message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        title: 'Women',
                        color: 'c20d00',
                        image: {
                            url: (Post.itemurl),
                        },
                    },
                })
                message.channel.send(Post.itemurl)
            });
      }).catch(console.error);
    },
};
```

If I add .gif to the embed link, just nothing shows up instead of showing the poop emoji error message in the embed. What am I supposed to do so it displays properly in an embed instead of just being sent as a message by itself [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F5sI.png) (Dont mind the weird gif tenor chose to send). I have also found other forums with similar issues and they solve it with adding .media before the .url property, but it also provides me with an error of
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'media' of undefined`, which then causes the issue of simply not displaying anything within the embed [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz2G8.png). `url: (Post.media[0].itemurl),`
Thanks

Comment: Is this your full code? Because I can't see "Tenor" defined here at all

Comment: First line was meant to be `const Tenor = require("tenorjs").client({` (Fixed)

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the tenor function would give ? So I can have a look at what's wrong with the link please

Comment: As in the result of the discord bot on discord? Its https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F5sI.png and the common solution of adding .media is also linked in post

Comment: I meant, what's the link specifically, not what you saw on discord but the actual link of gif, would be helpful to see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently its a part of discord's issue and they simply do not let tenor embeds work in a message embed, nothing I can do

Answer (score 0):

According to [tenorJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tenorjs) documentation, you get the url of the post with `Post.url` so try replacing `itemurl` with `URL`, it should output straight image url.

Comment: That isn’t right, I’ve already done that. URL simply refers to the shortened version of the link with around 7 numbers and letters while itemurl takes the link with the weird words to make the link. They are technically identical, I just prefer itemurl as it’s easier than url for trouble shooting purposes

Answer (score 0):

Late answer here but try console logging the Post object to find all the data stored there.

```
Post.media_formats.gif.url;
```